# Tweet blender takes a long time to show tweets

Tags: wordpress, twitter, plugins

On my wordpress site I have tweet blender plugin to show twitter tweets. Everything is ok except for some resason it takes a long time to show the tweets on my site. When tweet it takes anything between 15-70 minutes to show on my site. Any idea why is that? Everything should setted right.

Comment: Hey, I'm the author of Tweet Blender. Thanks for reporting this - I'll do some more testing of the @username|#hash behavior on my test blog but it would really help to see this on your site so I can setup my test box the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a link to the site? Perhaps Twitter was down?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see if any http requests are timing out, or if you have any script problems with the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to track down the problem. Its with hashtags. Without them it refresh tweets right away when I use example this @account|#hashtag it takes +30 minutues to refresh to the site/tweetblender. Is this normal with tweetblender?